# Reached end of file while parsing compilation error

Tags: parsing, compiler-errors

I am a java programming beginner. What did i do to get the error: reached end of file while parsing

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class eng{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String value; 
    String direct = "answer true or false to the following statement.";
    String ques = "Twelve is greater than seven";
    System.out.println(direct);
    System.out.println(ques);    
    value = input.nextLine();
    if ((value = "true")) {
      System.out.println("you are correct");
    } else {
       System.out.println("you are wrong my friend");              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add Another "}" at end of your code you missed one

2.There is another error in your code

```
if((value = "true"))
```

is not a proper way to check string equality and has syntax error it should be

```
if(value.equals("true"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're simply missing a closing brace `}`. From what the compiler sees you never closed the brace after `class eng{`

Comment: where should i put it?

Comment: @zeze-231 Each opening brace defines a new scope (generally speaking) so you would close it when you want that scope to end. In this case, since you're working on a Java file, the class is going to be the largest enclosing scope (as you work on more Java you'll see that statement isn't necessarily true, but for your purposes it is). Therefore the } you need would go after all other characters in the file. That is, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-indent/re-format your code first. Maybe you'll find a missing end brace "}".